# Get max timestamps efficiently for large table for a set of ids

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, database-partitioning

I have a large PostgreSQL db table (Actually lots of partition tables divided up by yearly quarters) that for simplicity sake is defined something like

```
id bigint
ts (timestamp)
value (float)
```

For a particular set of ids what is an efficient way of finding the last timestamp in the table for each specified id ?

The table is indexed by (id, timestamp)

If I do something naive like

```
SELECT sensor_id, MAX(ts) 
FROM sensor_values 
WHERE ts >= (NOW() + INTERVAL '-100 days') :: TIMESTAMPTZ 
GROUP BY 1;
```

Things are pretty slow.

Is there a way of perhaps narrowing down the times first by a binary search of one id
(I can assume the timestamps are similar for a particular set of ids)

I am accessing the db through psycopg so the solution can be in code or SQL if I am missing something easy to speed this up.

The explain for the query can be seen here. https://explain.depesz.com/s/PVqg

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: What is your Postgres version?

Comment: Postgres version 12.3

Comment: Just a stab in the dark (and more out of curiosity tbh) but what happens if you completely take out the where clause?

Comment: Without the where clause I had to stop the query after 15 minutes :)

Comment: I have a written a python method that looks for values going back a day at a time. Once I see data I can then get the last values quickly. Annoying it can't be done quickly or easily in sql.

Comment: What happens if you use a constant value in the WHERE clause? e.g. `where ts >= timestamp '2020-08-16 00:00:00'`?

Comment: When specifying a tighter timeframe things a fast. Its just the time taken with ordering lots of data I think when timespans are large. Thanks